# Orthonormal set and linear independence

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-explanation, inner-products

My book has this Theorem:

Let $A=\{v_1,v_2,\dots,v_n\}$ be an orthonormal subset of an inner product space $X$. Prove that $A$ is also linearly independent.

The proof it provides starts like this : $$\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k=0\implies \left\langle\,\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k,v_1\,\right\rangle=0$$ and then it shows that $λ_1=0$ and similarly you prove the same for the rest of $λ_k$.
Can you explain to me how this implication works? How you go from $\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k=0$ to $\left\langle\,\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k,v_1\,\right\rangle=0$ ?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you missed the word *orthonormal* when defining $A$ at the very beginning.

Comment: Because $\langle 0,v\rangle=0~\forall~v\in X$

Comment: @GNUSupporter yes, i fixed that. Prasun biswas i dont really get how that helps. Can you please give me more details?

Comment: Prasun says *for all* $v$, $\langle 0,v \rangle  = 0$.  In particular, $v = \sum \lambda_k v_k$

Answer (score 3):

Since $\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kv_k=0$,$$\left\langle\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kv_k,v_1\right\rangle=\langle0,v_1\rangle=0.$$

Comment: So, we take inner product with $v_1$ on both sides of the equation $\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_kv_k=0$ ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, although it is not an equation; it is an equality.

Answer (score 1):

Use directly the aximos of the inner product.

You use that $<\sum u_i,w>=\sum<u_i,w>$. Since your set is orthonormal $<u_i,u_j>=δ^i_j$.

Can you continue from here ?

Comment: Yes thank you. I just didn't understand how he jumped to the conclusion $\left\langle\,\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k,v_1\,\right\rangle=0$ from the $\sum_{k=1}^n λ_kv_k=0$. But I guess they aren't connected, he just takes inner product with $v_1$ on both sides.

Comment: You are exactly right.

Answer (score 1):

As was said in the comments below your question, the essential assumption you did not included is that the set $A$ is composed of *orthonormal* vectors, meaning $<v_i, v_j> = 0$ for $ i \neq j$ and $<v_i, v_i> \neq 0$ for all $i \in \{1, \dots, n \}  $. Then the proof goes as follows.

Since the inner product $< \cdot , \cdot > $ is bilinear (i.e. linear in each of its two slots) we have 
$$ < \sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k v_k, v_i> = \sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k < v_k, v_i> \ .$$
Using the orthonormality of the set $A$ we know that the above is equal to
$$ \sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k < v_k, v_i> = \lambda_i < v_i, v_i> \ .$$
From the assumption $< \sum_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k v_k, v_i> = 0$ we get 
$$ \lambda_i < v_i, v_i> = 0 $$
and thus $\lambda_i$ must be zero since $< v_i, v_i> \neq 0$. Repeating this procedure with different $v_k$ in the right slot of $< \cdot, \cdot > $ gives the proof of the statement.

Comment: I missed the fact that your question is only about the implication and not the  proof of the statement. Sorry if my post is somewhat missleading but hopefully it is not too much.

Comment: No problem, I got it and thanks. As mentioned in myother comments I thought that somehow the right side of the implication comes from the left side, but I guess that it just takes inner product on both sides with $v_1$.